# trying to copy file from one Gnu/Linux to another (on VMs), but getting ssh Permission denied

Tags: ssh, scp, aws, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have been trying to transfer file from one ec2 linux instance to another, so far I have tried

```
ssh -l ec2-user@<ip address>
```

in my source VM

I get

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

How to resolve this? Can anyone help me!

Comment: Edit question to tell us: Can you ssh to both from your local machine? Do you have the public key of user@machine1 installed on user@machine2?

Comment: The error message tells you that the remote machine does not accept password authentication; so as @ctrl-alt-delor said, you need to have your public key copied to the `authorized-keys` file on the remote machine.

Comment: Be careful not to override the old content of `authorized-keys`, because it will lock you out.

Comment: no i dont have public key of machine1 installed on machine2..can you please tell the command for it?..

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 instances use SSH keys for authentication via SSH. The private key that you used when deploying the EC2 instances, is the one that you need to use when you SCP between VMs

```
$ sudo scp -i /path/to/private/key /path/to/source/file user@X.X.X.X:/destination/path
```